# Linear Second Order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am working through a derivation of a second order differential equation from this [linked](https://www.nr.edu/chalmeta/267/kohler_section_3.01.pdf) document.  I have a question about the second derivative of (Y + y(t)) and getting y"(t).  Is it because Y is a considered a constant and so the second derivate of that is just zero?  I just need help clarifying that step.  Thank you.

[image: Starting equation]

[image: Resulting equation after differentiating]

Comment: The way I read it $Y$ is the length of the underwater portion of the body in the equilibrium position, and $y(t)$ is the displacement of the body from that position at time  t. I.e., $Y$ does not depend on $t$.

Comment: Ah ha!  Y is the constant from the equilibrium state so it does not depending on t.  I see.  Thank you!